# AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer running slower with time

Tags: ios, ios6, uiviewcontroller, avcapturesession

I have a UIViewController where i set an AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer on the init method to take pictures. When the photo is taken i dismiss the UIViewController.

Each time i open this UIViewController, the Ipad run slower until it crashes. I get a memory warning, so i think something its not being free, in the other hand, I am using ARC so i suppouse that each time i dismiss the UIViewController it frees the memory.

Here is the code on the init method of the UIViewController:

```
    session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium;

    AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *captureVideoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];
    captureVideoPreviewLayer.affineTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI+M_PI_2);
    captureVideoPreviewLayer.frame = CGRectMake(45, 55, 512, 387);
    [self.cameraPlace.layer addSublayer:captureVideoPreviewLayer];


    NSArray *cameras=[AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    AVCaptureDevice *device = [cameras objectAtIndex:1];

    NSError *error = nil;
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:&error];
    [session addInput:input];

    stillImageOutput = [[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *outputSettings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: AVVideoCodecJPEG, AVVideoCodecKey, nil];
    [stillImageOutput setOutputSettings:outputSettings];

    [session addOutput:stillImageOutput];

    [session startRunning];
```

Do i have something wrong? or do you have any clue?

Comment: How are you creating the VC? Do you have a property? Do you create a new VC each time?

Comment: Are you getting the memory warning while you are in the VC? What hapend if you open it once?

Comment: I am creating a ViewController each time i need ot take a picture: CameraViewController *camera = [[CameraViewController alloc] initWithBlackboard:self.farm mode:3];

Comment: I get the memory warning while the ViewController is opening, if i open only once the ViewController everything goes right

Comment: Did you add some reference to your VC? Sound like the VC isn't freed.

Comment: Here is the solution:
AVCaptureInput* input = [session.inputs objectAtIndex:0];
    [session removeInput:input];
    AVCaptureVideoDataOutput* output = [session.outputs objectAtIndex:0];
    [session removeOutput:output];
    [session stopRunning];

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem because I was adding a layer with a session that was already added.

```
self.captureVideoPreviewLayer = [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer 
                layerWithSession:self.session];
```

on the above line please set a breakpoint, you will observe it will take 3-4 seconds to proceed. Sometimes it creates a memory warning and sometimes it doesn't.
so just add check whether it is already added or not like below.

```
NSError *error;
[self.deviceCamera lockForConfiguration:&error];

if (self.session == nil)
{
    self.session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];  
    self.captureVideoPreviewLayer = [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer 
    layerWithSession:self.session];
    CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds];
    self.captureVideoPreviewLayer.frame = screenBounds;
    self.captureVideoPreviewLayer.videoGravity = 
    AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill; //  to fill the camera fullscreen view
    self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    if ([self.session canAddInput:_input]) {
        [self.session addInput:_input];
     }
}
  
[self.session startRunning];
      
[self.layer addSublayer:self.captureVideoPreviewLayer];
        
if (self.stillImageOutput ==  nil)
{
    self.stillImageOutput = [[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *outputSettings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: AVVideoCodecJPEG, AVVideoCodecKey, nil];
    [self.stillImageOutput setOutputSettings:outputSettings];
    NSString* preset = 0;
    if (!preset) {
        preset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto;
    }
    
    if ([self.session canSetSessionPreset:preset]) {
        
        self.session.sessionPreset = preset;
    }
    
    
    if ([self.session canAddOutput:self.stillImageOutput]) {
        [self.session addOutput:self.stillImageOutput];
    }
}
```

[objective-c](/questions/tagged/objective-c)  [ios](/questions/tagged/ios)  [avcapturesession](/questions/tagged/avcapturesession)